# Is there a way to customize keyboard shortcuts for Outlook 2013?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've searched a fair deal, but the [closest answer](http://www.techfeb.com/how-customize-microsoft-office-2013-keyboard-shortcuts/) I found was for Word 2013, but the same steps don't work for Outlook.

Is there a way to customize Outlook 2013's keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Does AutoHotKey allow you to override existing shortcuts, or only add new ones? I'm hoping to replace `ctrl-F` so instead of forwarding, it does a search.

Comment: Yes it can, check out its documentation: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm